# How to index a dataframe that contains lists/vectors as values

Tags: r, indexing, bioinformatics

Indexing a dataframe works for single values but not for values that are list elements or vectors.

I have two lists of the genes that I need to match up.  In each list, the genes are named as different gene aliases. I need to query a large list of genes in order to filter out any genes that are not shared between the two datasets.  To do this, I created a dataframe that contains all genes from both lists.  Each value in the dataframe is either a single string or a vector of multiple strings (aliases). A separate column assigns each group of aliases a unique number, which I am using to match the two lists. For each gene I need to check if it is present in the dataframe.  But I cannot index the vector values.  See below:

```
df <- data.frame("col1"=I(list(c("MALAT1","FTK2","CAS9"),
                                 "MS4A6A",
                                 c("LACT1","FLEE6","LOC98"))),
                 "col2"=I(list(c("CASS4","MS4A2","NME"), 
                               "PLD3", 
                               "ADAM4")))
"MALAT1" %in% df$col1
[1] FALSE
"MS4A6A" %in% df$col1
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is a `list`, we can `unlist`

```
"MALAT1" %in% unlist(df$col1)
#[1] TRUE
```

The reason, second one returns `TRUE` is because the second element is of `length` 1 while the one with "MALAT1" is not

-testing

If we change the `list` element that have a single element to "MALAT1"

```
df$col1[2] <- "MALAT1"
"MALAT1" %in% df$col1
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Generally, when we have a `list`, if we want to test on each element

```
lapply(df$col1, `%in%`, x = "LACT1")
#[[1]]
#[1] FALSE

#[[2]]
#[1] FALSE

#[[3]]
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there. Just wrap `unlist()` around the list you have your da

Answer (score 1):

Here is another workaround, which plays a trick on `df` by flattening the `list`s in columns via `rapply` + `toString`

```
df[] <- rapply(df, toString, how = "unlist")
```

such that

```
> df
                 col1              col2
1  MALAT1, FTK2, CAS9 CASS4, MS4A2, NME
2              MS4A6A              PLD3
3 LACT1, FLEE6, LOC98             ADAM4
```

and then you can use `grepl` to check if the objective can be found in the column via, e.g.,

```
> grepl("LACT1", df$col1, fixed = TRUE)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE

> grepl("NME", df$col2, fixed = TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks so much! great solution